# VM's Performance metric information in VCloudAir - java sdk

Tags: java, sdk, vmware, vcloud-director-rest-api

I'm using vCloud Java SDK 5.5 and I'm trying to access the historic usage of VM's Performance Metrics once I list all children VMs in vapp. I could not find any samples or guides on how to fetch details via Java SDK.  How could I do this?

Thanks.